# How to use a query with combobox value?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, combobox

I have a combobox with values.
And a mysql query.
But I do not know how to apply the value of the combobox within my query.

```
#COMBO TYPE
def combo_input_type(): 
        conn = connect_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = 'test 1'")
        #query = "SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = (%s)"
        #cursor.execute (query,combo_maker)
        result=cursor.fetchall()
        return result
#COMBO TYPE
```

I want to change `test 1` by my combo value.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value from the combobox, or using a parameter in a database statement? Both things are covered by existing documentation. Have you done any research or made any attempts before asking the question?

Comment: Yes but to late to answer.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#COMBO TYPE
def combo_input_type(): 
        combo_value= combobox.get() #value from your combo
        conn = connect_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = '%s'", [combo_value])
        #query = "SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = (%s)"
         #cursor.execute (query,combo_maker)
         result=cursor.fetchall()
         return result
 #COMBO TYPE
```

Get current value of Combo:

use get() method to get the element itself.

```
 combo_value= combobox.get()
```

Parametrized query:

we are passing a parameter (%s) for the values. You must supply values in place of the placeholders (%s) before you can execute this query using Prepared Statement. Here we provide python variables at the position of the placeholder.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = '%s'", [combo_value])
```

Comment: Good Morning! Sorry for answering late. That's works fine. Thanks you!!!

Comment: This leaves you open to a sql injection attacking. It probably doesn’t matter that much for a tkinter app